# Iterating the View Object getAllRowsInRange VS RowSetIterator

Tags: oracle-adf

I need to know is it correct to use **getAllRowsInRange**() instead of **RowSetIterator** .

as we know , we need to close the result set to avoid memory leak.

the Question is : Do the **getAllRowsInRange** method cause a memory leak ? and how to handle that ?

**--using getAllRowsInRange returninig array of Rows**

```
ViewObject vo =app.findViewObject("VoName");

   Row rows[] = vo.getAllRowsInRange();

   for(Row r : Rows){
      System.out.println("Attribute - " +r.getAttribute("AttributeName"));
     }
```

**--using createRowSetIterator returns a RowSetIterator we can close it**

```
 RowSetIterator rs = vo.createRowSetIterator(null); 
   rs.reset();
   while(rs.hasNext()){
                Row r = rs.next();
                System.out.println("r - " + r);
                System.out.println("Attribute - " +r.getAttribute("AttributeName"));
            }

    rs.closeRowSetIterator();
```

Comment: Imo always use RowSetIterator if you want to be sure you get all the rows. getAllRowsInRange() will only return the first N, defined by the range in the bindings.

Comment: @MihaiC **getAllRowsInRange** can get all records if set range size = -1 .

Comment: That is true, but do you always want to return the entire set from the database in a jsf page at once?

Comment: yes the application has a lot of calculations and always need all data to retrieve the correct calculation ,and this caused a memory leak.

Comment: Do you need to display any of the retrieved data in the jsf page? If not, and you just use it for calculations, why not simply create a method in your AppModuleImpl class which executes the query, and then passes through the vo with a rowSetIterator. You can close it and dispose of it anytime you need too. I still believe this is the best way to do it. There is absolutely no need to display the data in a page and use getAllRowsInRange if you just need it for calculations. Instead, just display the results of said calculations

Comment: yes i need to display it , the application has about 40 pages most of them need to show all data